# How to change the form of my cup to become more round

Tags: transforms

Do you know what would be the smartest way to make the form of my cup more round?
[image]

Comment: Try playing with "To Sphere"
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/to_sphere.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. select all your vertices

[image: https://youtu.be/IbuA-JinG4c]

2. Press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> and move mouse as you need it

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! that solved it!

Comment: You are welcome!!